# Summation (sigma) function

Tags: excel, vba, function, math, equation

I made a test function in excel using VBA but I keep getting an incorrect value of zero (correct answer should be 99).

My test values are as follows: N = 10, number = 9. The first picture is what I am trying to achieve. The second is the code that I have tried.

[image: Sigma function]

[image: Current VBA Code]

Comment: you do not return anything. `test = s` right before the `end function`

Comment: Ahhh I can't believe I forgot the return statement. Thank you so much!